# How can I use append correctly here? Am I following the directions correctly?

Tags: python

Write a function find_longest_word(wordList) that takes a list of words and returns the longest word in the list. If there are multiple longest words (i.e., with the same length), then it should return the first one among them (i.e., the one that appears before others in the list).

Write a program that asks the user to enter some words separated by space (all in one line). Your program then should create a list with the words entered (you can use the built-in split method in strings for this) and output the list and the longest word (using the above function).

Sample run:

Enter a few words and I will find the longest:

The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog

The list of words entered is:

['The', 'quick', 'brown', 'fox', 'jumps', 'over', 'the', 'lazy', 'dog']

The longest word in the list is:

quick

My code

```
    def find_longest_word():

    lizt=[]
    s = input("Please type a sentence and I will out put the longest word. ")

    for word in s:
        lizt.append(word)

    x = max(s.split(), key=len)



    print('')
    print('The list of words entered is:')
    print(lizt)
    print(s.split())
    print('')
    print('The longest word is:')
    print(x)

find_longest_word()
```

Comment: I don't understand what your question is?  Do you get the correct output?

Comment: Just note that if you aren't getting the output you expect, you should give the output and show what you want to have changed.  This makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 5):

```
for word in s:
        lizt.append(word)
```

This loop is wrong. `s` is a string, and `word in s` will iterate through each *letter* in `s`, not each space-separated word in it. You just need to use `.split()`, your variable `lizt` is unnecessary.

You *could* do:

```
lizt = []
for word in s.split():
    lizt.append(word)
```

but this would simply result in `lizt` being the same as `s.split()`. So `lizt = s.split()` would be simpler.

And if you *really* want to use a loop for this, you could try to forgo using `max` and do the following instead:

```
max_word, max_len = None, 0
for word in s.split():
    if len(word) > max_len:
        max_word, max_len = word, len(word)
```

but it'd be simpler and more pythonic to just use `split` and `max` and not have to write an explicit loop yourself.

Comment: For some reason I was under the impression I should do this with a loop! Thanks for the input.. Is there a way I could do this as a loop correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Using `for word in s:` will cause Python to go through every *character* of the string entered by the user.  You should use `lizt = s.split()` which will automatically make a list of `str` that were originally separated by a single space in the input.  This is what you want.

As a little side note, you can use arguments such as `s.split('\t')` to split the words using a different *delimiter*.  Example:

```
sentence = "Split function"
sentence.split() # -> ["Split", "function"]
sentence.split("i") # -> ["Spl","t funct","on"]
```

Regarding your usage of `append`, you do seem to understand how to append items to a `list`, so bravo.

Answer (score 0):

This code will do what you want, I think. The split method on the string, creates the word list. Then returning the max function, with the len function as the key gives you the longest word in the list. I.e. it finds the max value in the list, by applying len to each and returning the longest.

```
s = "Please type a sentence and I will out put the longest word"
s_list = s.split()

def longest_word(s_list)

    return max(s_list, key=len)
```

Comment: Odds are that the poster is using Python 3, so `input` is used in place of `raw_input`.